# Why I'm able to traverse these folders?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

Setting ntfs permissions should work but suddenly when I wanted to block for regular user **emp2** possibility to Traverse through catalogs it seems to not work.

[image]

There's as you see only SYSTEM, Administrators, wojtek(who belongs to Admins group) and finally this emp2 user.

Yes I tested it on emp2 - as showed on video, what - as I said is not visible on static image. Yes I know theory from https://www.ntfs.com , but theory way way and real - other way (most often not working as intended ) So as I said final goal was to now allow to go-througts underlaying catalogs but emp2 can visit all subfolders inside :(

Comment: Traverse Folder means going into a folder. Have you tested that for the user emp2?

Comment: Traverse Folder: Allows or denies **moving through a restricted folder to reach files and folders beneath the restricted folder** in the folder hierarchy.

Comment: [NTFS.com. All about NTFS file system](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm)

Comment: Yes I tested it on emp2 - as showed on video, what - as I said is not visible on static image. Yes I know theory from https://www.ntfs.com , but theory way way and real - other way (most often not working as intended ) So as I said final goal was to now allow to go-througts underlaying catalogs but emp2 can visit all subfolders inside :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users have the
[Bypass Traverse Checking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc739389%28v=ws.10%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
user right by default, so your permissions have no effect.

This is set in the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) at the branch of
*Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment*,
by the policy named
"Bypass traverse checking".

It is defined as:

> This user right determines which users can traverse directory trees even though the user may not have permissions on the traversed directory. This privilege does not allow the user to list the contents of a directory, only to traverse directories.

By default, this policy includes the "Everyone" group.
Changing this might cause serious malfunctions for the computer.

You should look for another method, such as assigning positive permission to
some files and folders, but denying everything else.
Changing the Bypass Traverse Checking policy should be avoided.

Comment: ahhh, so it explain a little. So by default (if nothing is/was changed in Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) then this checkbox "Traverse folder" checked or unchecked is not functional anymore for everyone - am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's so.

Comment: So it provide me to next related checkbox-1 below from Traverse -List folder. Keeping in mind that without changing Traverse behaviour in GPE(gpedit.msc) Traverse is "not working" I thought about blocking visibility of folder/subfolder contents - in fact checkbox Listing folder.Does it work as intended - because when I unchecked it (so in fact Listing folder and traverse was unchecked) and logged as emp2 I was unable to open folder.So It looks List folder works like Traverse blocker. I expected that I'm able to go inside folder but not see content - becouse of blocked listing.Is it broken too?